# CSS3 Border Radius Not Working for div element

Tags: html, css

I'm new in Web. everything was fine but in the case border-radius not working in browser anyone like chrome/FF.
The CSS code like this :

```
.work-step div {
color: #e67e22;
margin: 2px solid #e67e22;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 50%; //not working
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 120%;
margin-left: 25px;
```

}

Comment: Not that it would prevent your border-radius from working, but you're margin property (`margin: 2px solid #e67e22;`) is incorrect. You'll also likely have to show more code to find the problem. `border-radius: 50%` is a valid property & value so you're problem likely is deriving from somewhere else.

Comment: why Margin property incorrect or what should be?

Comment: actually there working everything fine only without border-radius. i don't know how to solve. I was following someone lectures.

Comment: The value you are using for your margin is similar to the value you would pass for a border. You can see acceptable values for the `margine` property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer , anyone looking at this in the future overflow:hidden; does the magic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.work-step {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #e67e22;
    margin: 2px solid #e67e22;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain your answer? also, your CSS code is invalid...

Comment: the value for `margin` is invalid, margin can't take `solid` nor a hex code

Comment: The problem asked was for the border radius. I solved that problem. I haven't checked for other problem, sorry