# Border radius on parent div

Tags: html, css

There are three divs that are inside the parent div with `display:flex`.

I want to create a border-radius for parent div but something doesn't work.

My code is:

```html
<div style="height:50px;display:flex;width:500px;border-radius: 20px;">
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:red"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:40%;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

The border-radius is invisible. It is possible for the child to have `width:0%` or `width:100%` so the border-radius should be applied for the parent container.

How is it possible to to that?

Comment: add overflow: hidden to parent.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing child to obey parent's curved borders in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714862/forcing-child-to-obey-parents-curved-borders-in-css)

Comment: check my answer, it should help out out :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 Border Radius Not Working for div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592610/css3-border-radius-not-working-for-div-element)

Answer (score 10):

add `overflow:hidden` to parent div

```html
<div style="height:50px;display:flex;width:500px;border-radius: 20px;overflow:hidden">
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:red"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:40%;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: down-voted for following reasons: Missing content. Even though your anwser would solve the OP`s issue, this anwser could incl. more content and formatting. It should at least contain a working snippet as the other anwser or be given as an upvote to the identical comment that was given before.

Comment: even then more content could have been used and espacially a workign snippet for validation. An 1 sentence anwser in most cases is not helpful as an anwser and would have been sufficient as a comment.

Comment: it is still the correct answer though @tacoshy

Comment: @tacoshy Ok I edited my question. but you need to ask you the following: what is more important to you? a correct answer, or correct formatting?

Comment: they are both important. Its not a question of what is more important. It takes literally 5 seconds to add a code snippet for validation (which btw. I added for you). It also literally takes 1 second to highlight code lines instead of posting them unformatted. You could write an article without any punction or formatting. The article could contain true information, however you would surely agree that the article would be hard to read, if not being unreadable. As such it would be low-quality no matter if the content is true or not.

Comment: I disagree, the correct answer is the most important thing - especially if the task is very simple!, I of course post more complex answers in code formatting, but for something like this which is only one line? I dont't understand this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231186/discussion-between-daniel-resch-and-tacoshy).

Answer (score 2):

Just gotta add `overflow: hidden` to the parent div **OR** apply the border-radius to the first and last children. Sometimes, certain elements don't react nicely to the parent clipping them and respond better to being clipped directly. Here are both methods:

**Border-radius on parent:**

```css
body > div {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:50px;display:flex;width:500px;">
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:red"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:40%;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

**Border-radius on children:**

```css
body > div > div:first-child {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
body > div > div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:50px;display:flex;width:500px;">
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:red"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:40%;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div style="height:50px;display:flex;width:500px;border-radius: 20px;overflow: hidden">
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:red"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:30%;background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height:50px;width:40%;background:yellow"></div>
</div>
```

so adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent should fix the problem